# Marklogic ServerConnectionException, xdmp:node-replace

Tags: marklogic

Marklogic xdmp:node-replace is failing and getting below exception;

```
MarkLogic: ServerConnectionException, Premature EOF, partial header line read: ''
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: Premature EOF, partial header line read: ''
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Premature EOF, partial header line read: ''
```

Some more details;

1. Marklogic version is 5
2. Application is executing xquery via xcc connector
3. Not all the xqueries are failing but xdmp:node-replace fails every
   time
4. Importantly dashboard/diskspace shows Forest reserve having enough
   memory but Free space is 0 MB, If this could be the reason then how
   other queries are executing and why there is no disk space error in
   the marklogic logs.

Comment: If free space is zero, then MarkLogic has no room to write disk space errors to the logs. Zero free space is a very unhealthy situation, and will not only affect operation of MarkLogic, but potentially entire OS.

Comment: The other queries, do they make updates as well?

Comment: Yes there are queries making updates, precisely queries that inserts new nodes in existing xml structures like xdmp:node-insert-*

Comment: I have some more information on this. The ServerConnectionException is coming only when the size of post data is more than 20 MB.

Comment: @grtjn Hi grtjn, Any idea what could be the problem? We are using rsuite cms, I debug more into this and found that rsuite is sending 25 MB of data to marklogic and it fails at some point in marklogic without processing the request. When I reduced the data size to 20 MB then marklogic processed the request. So it seems like the size of payload is a problem.